# What is this called (JS)

Tags: javascript

```
var logic = {
    Rock: { w:"Scissors", l:"Paper"},
    Paper: {w:"Rock", l:"Scissors"},
    Scissors: {w:"Paper", l:"Rock"},
};
```

and it is used like:

```
logic[playChoice].w === rndChoice
```

Found it in a JS rock paper scissors example, curious what logic is called.

Please let me know if this is the wrong place...

Comment: It's just referencing properties in an object

Comment: `logic` is an Object with properties `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Scissors` which are also Objects with `w` and `l` properties which are Strings. You can access an Object property like `logic.Rock` or with a String, like `logic['Rock']`. It looks like `playChoice` is a `var`iable that is being passed inside the brackets. `===` is an exact comparison operator, that must represent `'Rock'`, `'Paper'` or `'Scissors'`. So this code might be really testing something like `if(logic['Paper'].w === 'Scissors'){ /* yeah, that's the winner */ }`

Comment: What is what called, the `logic` object or the usage?

Comment: It is sometimes known as a *map* or an *associative array*. It is common to use this in place of `switch` or `if`/`else` statements.

Comment: @killahtree On SO you can only have one "official" answer, in case you thought you could mark multiple as the answer (I noticed the check mark was jumping around at one point). I'm not sure which answer you meant, I just thought I'd let you know in case you weren't aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about the exact javascript structure that is being used here in the variable called `logic`, to store the data, that is just a nested* `object`, created via an object literal.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

*: Meaning, that the values stored in the object are objects themselves as well.

In case you are curious about the more generic answer, things assigning values to keys are usually referred to as `maps`. (When the values are consecutive numbers starting from zero, we essentially get an `array`.)

I strongly recommend that you read through this to get a better understanding:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
var logic = {
    Rock: { w:"Scissors", l:"Paper"},
    Paper: {w:"Rock", l:"Scissors"},
    Scissors: {w:"Paper", l:"Rock"},
};

logic[playChoice].w === rndChoice
```

`logic` is an object. Just a regular object with the properties `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Scissors`. Each of these properties are also objects, each with a win property (`w`) and a loss property (`l`). These properties are set to the string values of each available input.

The comparison (`===`) uses two variables not previously defined, `playChoice`, provided by the player and `rndChoice`, provided by the computer. If the `w` property for the object in the property for `playChoice` equals the `rndChoice` the comparison is true, and the player wins the round.

For example:

1. We play `Rock`
2. The computer plays `Scissors`
3. The left side of the comparison gets the `w` property of `logic["Rock"]`, or `"Scissors"`
4. the left side matches the right side that was selected by the computer
5. The comparison is true, the player has won the round

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is accessing an attribute of object "logic" with a given key.

The object "logic" here is a nested object, where the keys are in itself objects as well.

If `playChoice === Rock` then we are accessing the Rock object from the logic object, and grabbing the "w" attribute from Rock.